# SDK Location not found although ANDROID_HOME is set

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an Android app using Gradle on Ubuntu 18.04. Android Studio is not installed o the machine (I use Eclipse for development but maintain a gradle toolchain).

The toolchain has worked on a different machine running Ubuntu 16.04. However, it does not work with gradle 3.4.1, which ships with 18.04, so I had to upgrade my build config. On the 18.04 machine, I changed the dependency

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

and changed

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

Now when I run `gradle build`, I get the following error message:

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

However, I have `ANDROID_HOME` set and pointing to `~/bin/android-sdk-linux`, which is the root dir of my Android SDK setup. Also, I have Android SDK build tools 25.0.3 installed locally.

What gives?

Comment: Open **local.properties** file in project root and check whether **sdk.dir=.../android_sdk** line is defined or not ?

Comment: There is no local.properties file, I rely completely on `ANDROID_HOME`.

Comment: what do you mean by `I rely completely on`, this file is auto created when you define sdk path

Comment: As documented this file is used by Gradle to locate your android sdk, I think you are getting error as gradle could not find you sdk.

Comment: The file doesn’t exist (I started this project on a different machine and then cloned the git repo, which shouldn’t contain any files with local configuration). My reading of the error message is that, without that file, Gradle will use `ANDROID_HOME` to determine the SDK path. However, after creating this file, the error seems to disappear (though I’m getting another, probably unrelated one).

Comment: I think your `ANDROID_HOME` and `sdk.dir` are different.. can you check that?

Comment: Just checked again, both contain the same path (I created the file with `echo sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME > local.properties`).

Comment: you said you got new error, can you stat that ?

Comment: `Failed to notify project evaluation listener. javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema`

Comment: Please try disabling the Instant Run and Rebuild your project ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173333/discussion-between-user149408-and-mohit).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Gradle does not honor `ANDROID_HOME`, despite the error message saying otherwise.

As a workaround,

```
echo sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME >> local.properties
```

in the project root dir has fixed this (after also ensuring I was using the correct JDK version and had all submodules checked out).

Oddly, however, on a different computer (also running Ubuntu 18.04) the same app builds without `local.properties` being present.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no local.properties, just go ahead and create one in parallel to gradle directory.

Then add this line,
sdk.dir=/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk