# Android SDK is not found although ANDROID_HOME is set successfully (android Studio on MacOS)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I've freshly installed AndroidStudio on MacOS Big Sur 11.6.2 to create a NativeScript project.

Installation went smoothly. However, when I run `ns doctor android`, it complains that Android SDK is not set: "`✖ Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later.`"

But `ANDROID_HOME` is successfully set! I use zsh, so the configuration is located in `.zshrc`, here it is:

```
###-tns-completion-start-###
if [ -f /Users/testuser/.tnsrc ]; then 
    source /Users/testuser/.tnsrc
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/testuser/Library/Android/sdk
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

fi
###-tns-completion-end-###
```

If I type `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, output is correct: `/Users/testuser/Library/Android/sdk`. For safety, I also checked if it would work when using `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, no success.

Furthermore, if I check `Preferences` in AndroidStudio --> `AndroidSDK` --> `SDK Platforms`, it shows `Android API 32` together with the correct path shown above.

Additionally installed:

- Android SDK Build Tools - 32
- NDK (side by side)
- Android SDK Command-line tools
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform Tools
- ... as well as all SDK Update sites.

In `Project Structure`, the correct Android SDK location is listed (`/Users/testuser/Library/Android/sdk`).

I checked if `/Users/testuser/Library/Android/sdk` really exists, and it does. Everything is there.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908552/sdk-location-not-found-although-android-home-is-set) solution didn't work. Invalidate caches and restart as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395368/android-studio-run-configuration-asks-to-select-android-sdk-although-sdk-is-conf) doesn't work also. `local.properties` with the SDK path as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673378/where-does-local-properties-go-for-android-project) is already preset by AndroidStudio, pointing to: `sdk.dir=/Users/testuser/Library/Android/sdk`.

I'm desperate and don't know what to do anymore. Who can help me? Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you get any working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to the standard "Android SDK Tools" being marked as "Obsolete" in Android Studio.

- Depending on your AS version, either uncheck "Hide Obsolete Packages" or check "Obsolete" so obsolete options are displayed.
- Select and install "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)".
- Once that completed, add the following lines to your `.zshrc` profile with the rest of the exports:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on linux, I have `/home/user/Android/Sdk` instead of `...Android/sdk` in after installing AS.

Solved it by simply linking `sdk` to `Sdk`

`ln -s /home/$USER/Android/Sdk /home/$USER/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy8AV.png) helped me to resolve the error -

```
android could NOT be found in /Users/{user_name}/Library/Android/sdk!
```

**Sharing a screenshot for helping the community**

[image]